# MsBuild failing to build package, but okay with "just" building or building package after a "normal" build

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a problem with building a Web Deployment Package from a Web Application Project (within a solution containing multiple projects, as well as multiple web applications).

**This actually works**

I can build the project just fine from the command line if I use this command for example:

```
msbuild D:\PathTo\Solution\Project\Project.csproj
    /fl /flp:logfile="D:\buildadventures\Build.log";errorsonly;verbosity=diagnostic
    /p:SolutionDir="D:\PathTo\Project\\";Configuration=Release;Platform=AnyCpu
```

**But this does not work**

But when I try the same command just a bit differently to build a deployment package for me like that:

```
msbuild D:\PathTo\Solution\Project\Project.csproj
    /fl /flp:logfile="D:\buildadventures\Build.log";errorsonly;verbosity=diagnostic
    /T:Package
    /p:SolutionDir="D:\PathTo\Solution\\";Configuration=Release;Platform=AnyCpu;
    PackageLocation="D:\buildadventures\Project.zip";
    AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false
```

...it fails miserably, spitting out hundreds of errors of the "The type or namespace name '' does not exist"-kind

**And why does it work this way?**

The strange thing however is, the second command I posted works fine if the first one was executed prior to that.

I suppose the tasks executed when doing a "normal" build are different to those that are executed when building a package, now I wonder in what way they are different.

**What symptomatically seems to cause it**

I noticed that in the project file of the project I want to build a package of contains a custom section towards the end:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>
        cscript $(ProjectDir)SvnRevision\svnrevision.vbs $(ProjectDir) $(ProjectDir)Version.cs
        nuget install "$(ProjectDir)packages.config" -o "$(SolutionDir)Packages"
    </PreBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This seems to be responsible for that difference; if I do a "normal" build I can see that after that a new "Packages" directory was created in my solution folder.
However, as you might have guessed, that directory is missing when I try to do the package creation command. I also do not run into this problem if I let Visual Studio create the package for me.

Maybe I do have to change the project file or passed properties to carry over this behavior for my package creation, too?

Or Is there maybe a way to force a "normal" build and then just append package creation to that somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me.
I was able to circumvent this issue by just calling multiple targets in my msbuild command such as that:

```
msbuild D:\PathTo\Solution\Project\Project.csproj
    /fl /flp:logfile="D:\buildadventures\Build.log";errorsonly;verbosity=diagnostic
    /t:Build;Package
    /p:SolutionDir="D:\PathTo\Solution\\";Configuration=Release;Platform=AnyCpu;
    PackageLocation="D:\buildadventures\Project.zip";
    AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false
```